# killing a thread from within in a form

Tags: c#, multithreading, crystal-reports

my application calls crystal reports viewer to display a report. I run the report viewer in a separate thread. It works just fine. it displays the report properly. my problem is i want to kill the report while it is processing if it is taking too long to run. While the report is processing the busy indicator is spinning and it seems to block any UI on the report viewer form. My report viewer form has a crystal reports viewer on it along with a close button at the bottom of the form itself. i would like to be able to click the close button and have it stop the processing. Here is my code to run the viewer in a single apartment thread

```
 public void RunReportStep1(UAReport report)
    {
        UAReportService service = new UAReportService(report);
        service.RunReport();
        var reportDocument = service.ReportDocument;  

        Thread staThread = new Thread(r => { RunReportStep2((ReportDocument) r); });
        staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        staThread.Start(reportDocument);
        staThread.Join();
    }

    public void RunReportStep2(ReportDocument reportDocument)
    {
        ReportViewerForm form = new ReportViewerForm(reportDocument);
        form.BringToFront();
        form.ShowDialog();
        if (form.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }
```

what is the best way to kill the thread from within the report viewer form while the processing is going on. Once the processing completes and the report is destroyed closing the report is no problem. It's only a problem while the processing is going on before the report is displayed. While the report is processing the close button is not responsive. sometimes if i click it repeatedly i can get a response and the report cancels. but it is not consistent and i have to click it repeatedly. that is not acceptable for my clients to have to do.

Comment: Did my answer help or did you figure it out on your own? If I helped, please accept my answer, or at least up-vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call the service.RunReport() from another thread and wait for that thread to finish or for a certain amount of time to pass. I didn't write all the code for this, but anything I didn't write I a least described.

```
    // Global so it can be reached from both threads
    UAReportService service;

    // Global variable that is written to when the report doc is ready:
    ReportDocType reportDoc; //Can't use var here unfortunately

    public void RunReportStep1(UAReport report)
    {
        service = new UAReportService(report);
        Thread staThread = new Thread(r => { RunReportStep2((UAReportService)r); });
        staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        staThread.Start(service);

        // Save time the thread started:
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        // Display a loading box (label or something, up to you). 
        // Then this function will end and your user can do stuff in the UI again (like press Cancel).
        myLoadingBox.Visible = true;
    }

    public void RunReportStep2(UAReportService service)
    {
        service.RunReport();
        reportDocument = service.ReportDocument;
    }

    // Call this new function periodically to see if the service thread finished, maybe once every second.
    public checkAndDisplay()
    {
        // If thread is finished or 30 seconds have passed.
        if (staThread.IsAlive == false || (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds > 30)
        {
            // Show a message saying report failed to run
        }
        else // Else you can now show your report viewer
        {
            ReportViewerForm form = new ReportViewerForm(reportDocument);
            form.BringToFront();
            form.ShowDialog();
            if (form.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    // Code for cancelling the report service call if user presses cancel button.
    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Terminate the report service thread.
        staThread.Abort();

        // Abort() isn't the nicest way to do this so if you can set a timeout on the UAReportService object (where it quits running after so long) that would be better. 
        // Or have it periodically check a variable to see if it should quit (see link below)
    }
```

[MSDN example of gracefully closing a thread.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)